# Can I build my html with dynamic Schema.org markup?

Tags: seo, markup, schema.org, structured-data

I have a page for Mobile application details and features, but the app itself is not implemented yet and not available on any store, so I don't know the size,version,rating etc..

The question is can I render the page with dynamic Schema.org markup, which means to build now for example as an [Article](https://schema.org/Article) markup, and once the app is live the page will be built with [MobileApplication](https://schema.org/MobileApplication) ? Can I do this and Google will like it and understand it? if not, what can I do for my case?

```
@if(IsAppLive){
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MobileApplication">
}
else{
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: @unor I am not asking for SEO advice, I don't know whether it gonna work or not, so I think it's a technical issue

Comment: This is the part asking for SEO advice: "Can I do this and Google will like it and understand it?" -- Questions about what search engine services do/allow/like/etc. are typically not on-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but Google will only scrape and index one version. It won't register a second version until it re-scrapes, which can take up to two weeks.